# Publish WCF service application using File system publish method in visual studio 2012

Tags: wcf, visual-studio-2012, publishing, publish-profiles

I want to publish WCF service in my local system using File system publish method. In Publish method i have given "File system", Target location as "C:\inetpub\wwroot\wcfpublish" and destination url as "https://wcf.publish.net:11096/Default.html".       But when i click on publish error message is coming saying "Fail to open url of https://wcf.publish.net:11096/Default.html. Exception: Class not registered".  I have configured in host file also., Please guide me

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, when doing a `FileSystem` publish, the `publishUrl` actually points to file path rather than a Url as the name would suggest.

Try setting `PublishUrl` to `C:\inetpub\wwroot\wcfpublish`.

Comment: yes in visualstudio 2010 if we mention as file path, then its working fine. but visualstudio2012 that no happening